# How does the shunt mmf in a long-shunt compound DC motor remain the same?

Tags: dc, electric-machine

In a circuit model like this, the textbook says that the shunt mmf is the same for no-load and fully loaded conditions of the motor. How is this possible when the armature current (Ia) changes?
[image]

Comment: Because a shunt winding isn't in series with the armature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If \$V_t\$ remains constant then shunt current remains constant and because MMF (magneto motive force) is current multiplied by number of turns, MMF remains constant. It's got nothing to do with armature current as this will affect only the series winding MMF.

Comment: But would the MMF be same when motor is operated at full-load and no-load conditions? (Does Vt change in this instance?)

Comment: @DeviprasadVR if you change \$V_t\$ then the shunt MMF changes proportionately. \$V_t\$ is the supply voltage to the motor so, it's defined by whatever control system is driving the motor.

Comment: So does the shunt field MMF change when the a load is added ?

Comment: The shunt MMF is wholly defined by the shunt resistance and \$V_t\$. Mechanical load on the motor has no effect on shunt current.

Comment: Oh so that that's how it's independent of the load. Thank you!